# Possible sql injection

Tags: sql, ruby, oracle, ruby-on-rails-3, squeel

I'm using [squeel gem](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel) in my project, and I have code something like this :

```
def self.search(query)
    return self.scoped if query.blank?

    self.joins(:supplier).where{lower(supplier.supplier_name).like_any(["%#{query}%"])}
  end
```

My questions is this code vulnerable to SQL injection? And how do I fix it? I tried to do `sanitize(query)` but it just adds extra set of quotes and the SQL statement doesn't get generated appropriately

Comment: Is this from Sequel? Looks like it could be from Squeel gem instead: https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel - please clarify because the vulnerability or not to SQL injection is going to depend which library. I suspect it is *not* vulnerable though, most of these libraries carefully escape params used for queries.

Comment: @NeilSlater you're right, let me edit the question, feel free to answer thanks

Comment: Well I could of answered if it was Sequel . . . but I don't have ActiveRecord db set up, and don't know for sure, although I suspect your code is not vulnerable. Hopefully someone who knows better will be able to answer with more confidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

Squeel will automatically escape strings, so your query is fine and won't open you up to injection. See [question about sql injection - Squeel - Github](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel/issues/136)

**OLD (INCORRECT) ANSWER:**
*This is the active record version*

Someone correct me if i'm wrong, but since you are passing in #{query} as a STRING and not an argument, then you are opening yourself up to injection. See [the docs for passing in arguments](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments)

Using arguments will escape the 'query' STRING

**Your query using arguments:**

```
self.joins(:supplier).where{lower(supplier.supplier_name).like_any(["%"+?+"%"], query)}
```